# Magento2. Customer repository change attribute does not work

Tags: magento2.2, customer-attribute, save

Everything is simple as an egg, but it does not work. Please help to figure out why. If you need more details - please let me know.

```
/**
 * @param int $customerId
 * @param int $addressId
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function setDefaultBillingAddress($customerId, $addressId)
{
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
    $customer->setDefaultBilling($addressId);
    $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
}
```

Customer is loading well, address with such ID exists. When I dived into `customerRepository->save($customer)` from the beginning everything is also well, but at some moment (probably when it saves customer to registry and tries to load it again - my new value is lost)

## Upd.1 Is it core issue?

> Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository (row. 236)

Magento removes customer from registry for some reason, then tries to load it from registry. It doesn't exist there and load from DB. Is it ok? Customer wasn't saved because it happen between beginTransaction() and commit()

## Upd.2

It refers only to this particular attribute **default_billing**, saving customer **firstname** work well

## Upd.3

The issue is near backend model of **default_billing** attribute. It has following code:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $object
 * @return void
 */
public function afterSave($object)
{
    if ($defaultBilling = $object->getDefaultBilling()) {
        $addressId = false;
        /**
         * post_index set in customer save action for address
         * this is $_POST array index for address
         */
        foreach ($object->getAddresses() as $address) {
            if ($address->getPostIndex() == $defaultBilling) {
                $addressId = $address->getId();
            }
        }
        if ($addressId) {
            $object->setDefaultBilling($addressId);
            $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
        }
    }
}
```

It looks for some **post_index** flag, which doesn't exist anywhere. Searching for **post_index** or **postIndex** don't give more results, than those from backend models (billing, shipping)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work described approach. Use following code:

```
/**
 * @param int $addressId
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function setDefaultBillingAddress($addressId)
{
    $address = $this->addressRepository->getById($addressId);
    $address->setIsDefaultBilling(1);
    $this->addressRepository->save($address);
}
```